# How to add traversed maze locations to a stack in java

Tags: java, maze

I'm trying to to see if a maze like this is solvable:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

So far I have created a 2D array of points...
Now how can I iterate through the 2D array and push them onto a stack in order to check if that location has been check or not yet?

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;


public class MazeExplorer {

    private static final int mazeHeight = 12;
    private static final int mazeWidth = 58;
    public static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];

    private static final boolean S = true;
    private static final boolean O = true;
    private static final boolean W = false;
    private static final boolean F = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        File f = new File("Maze1.txt");

        Stack<Point> points = new Stack<>();
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
            final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
            mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive methods are usually used for searching.

This is a depth first search for the exit. Returns true if exit is found.

```
public boolean searchForExit(Location myLocation){
    if(location.isFinish()){
        location.setSolutionPath(true);
        return true;
    }
    location.setVisited(true);
    for(Location location : location.getNeighbours()){
        if(!location.isVisited()){
            if (searchForExit(location)){
                location.setSolutionPath(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about iterating by changing the Os into Ss ?
For instance:

At step 0:

WSOOOOFW

Step 1:

WSSOOOFW

[..]

WSSSSSFW

When an S in next to F then it is solvable :)

On the other side, you can choose the condition to be unsolvable:
 - if after length+width turns, you didn't find F, it is not solvable
 - if at one step, you don't change any O in S, it is not solvable.

I suppose you get a double array of char of which you iterate.

```
public boolean myProc(char[][] maze) {
  boolean isSolvable = true;
  for (int iteration = 0; i < maze.length + maze[0].length; i++) {
    for (int height = 1 ; height < maze.length - 1; height++) {
      for (int width = 1 ; width < maze.length - 1; width++) {
        if(maze[height][width] == 'S') {
          if(maze[height + 1][width] == 'F') { return true; }
          if(maze[height + 1][width] == 'O') { maze[height + 1][width] = 'S'; }
          // do  the same for other adjacent parts
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now this version is not effective at all and I know it, I just wanted to show somethings that could work. Recursive versions could be good too if you ensure that you don't recurse forever.

Comment: But how do I know this is checking whether or not the maze is traversable instead of just changing all O to S?  Could you edit your answer to show an example-code?

Comment: Edited, do it only when an 'S' is adjacent to an 'O'

Comment: SO can you show me how to add the searched(now 'S') locations to a stack?